# How can I display images of different sizes in this way? And is there jquery plugins to do that

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, css-position

How can I display images of different sizes in this way? And is there jquery plugins to do that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELll7.png

I noticed from inspect that he manipulates top and left properties and he gave images absolute position and dad fixed height so they don't pop out of elements, I tried to do it in CSS, but I think it needs javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That style is called masonry, and yes, there are JQuery plugins that will help you achieve that. You will need to define a CSS Grid along with its elements, though. Here's a plugin for Masonry galleries,

https://masonry.desandro.com/#install

You'll need to add the file to your final website for it to work.